# Can't disable horizontal scroll in Datatables header

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatables

I've been using datatables for my companies website. But recently in latest versions of Chrome and Edge (older versions work just fine) start to broke things. One of them is the datatable head part. Tables supposed to move horizontally with header and body parts attached  and moving together. But now the header part and body part are completely independent and header part appeared to have a horizontal scroller out of nowhere (as in the screenshot below).

[image]

I've tried to set the header position as sticky and overflow-x: hidden but no luck. Here are some parts of my code which can be related with the issue. Also, I can add further details if needed. (P.S: these codes are implemented in a PHP script)

Here is a working replica of what I built, here the table seems fine but in the website its like in the picture above and I can't figure out why.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
       scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        fixedHeader:           {
            header: true,
            footer: true
        },
        ajax: 'data/arrays.txt',
      
      "data": [
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",
      "5421",
      "2011/04/25",
      "$320,800"
    ],
    [
      "Garrett Winters",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "8422",
      "2011/07/25",
      "$170,750"
    ],
    [
      "Ashton Cox",
      "Junior Technical Author",
      "San Francisco",
      "1562",
      "2009/01/12",
      "$86,000"
    ],
    [
      "Cedric Kelly",
      "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "Edinburgh",
      "6224",
      "2012/03/29",
      "$433,060"
    ],
    [
      "Airi Satou",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "5407",
      "2008/11/28",
      "$162,700"
    ],
    [
      "Brielle Williamson",
      "Integration Specialist",
      "New York",
      "4804",
      "2012/12/02",
      "$372,000"
    ],
    [
      "Herrod Chandler",
      "Sales Assistant",
      "San Francisco",
      "9608",
      "2012/08/06",
      "$137,500"
    ],
    [
      "Rhona Davidson",
      "Integration Specialist",
      "Tokyo",
      "6200",
      "2010/10/14",
      "$327,900"
    ],
    [
      "Colleen Hurst",
      "Javascript Developer",
      "San Francisco",
      "2360",
      "2009/09/15",
      "$205,500"
    ],
    [
      "Sonya Frost",
      "Software Engineer",
      "Edinburgh",
      "1667",
      "2008/12/13",
      "$103,600"
    ],
    [
      "Jena Gaines",
      "Office Manager",
      "London",
      "3814",
      "2008/12/19",
      "$90,560"
    ],
    [
      "Quinn Flynn",
      "Support Lead",
      "Edinburgh",
      "9497",
      "2013/03/03",
      "$342,000"
    ],
    [
      "Charde Marshall",
      "Regional Director",
      "San Francisco",
      "6741",
      "2008/10/16",
      "$470,600"
    ],
    [
      "Haley Kennedy",
      "Senior Marketing Designer",
      "London",
      "3597",
      "2012/12/18",
      "$313,500"
    ],
    [
      "Tatyana Fitzpatrick",
      "Regional Director",
      "London",
      "1965",
      "2010/03/17",
      "$385,750"
    ],
    [
      "Michael Silva",
      "Marketing Designer",
      "London",
      "1581",
      "2012/11/27",
      "$198,500"
    ],
    [
      "Paul Byrd",
      "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)",
      "New York",
      "3059",
      "2010/06/09",
      "$725,000"
    ],
    [
      "Gloria Little",
      "Systems Administrator",
      "New York",
      "1721",
      "2009/04/10",
      "$237,500"
    ],
    [
      "Bradley Greer",
      "Software Engineer",
      "London",
      "2558",
      "2012/10/13",
      "$132,000"
    ],
    [
      "Dai Rios",
      "Personnel Lead",
      "Edinburgh",
      "2290",
      "2012/09/26",
      "$217,500"
    ],
    [
      "Jenette Caldwell",
      "Development Lead",
      "New York",
      "1937",
      "2011/09/03",
      "$345,000"
    ],
    [
      "Yuri Berry",
      "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)",
      "New York",
      "6154",
      "2009/06/25",
      "$675,000"
    ],
    [
      "Caesar Vance",
      "Pre-Sales Support",
      "New York",
      "8330",
      "2011/12/12",
      "$106,450"
    ],
    [
      "Doris Wilder",
      "Sales Assistant",
      "Sydney",
      "3023",
      "2010/09/20",
      "$85,600"
    ],
    [
      "Angelica Ramos",
      "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
      "London",
      "5797",
      "2009/10/09",
      "$1,200,000"
    ],
    [
      "Gavin Joyce",
      "Developer",
      "Edinburgh",
      "8822",
      "2010/12/22",
      "$92,575"
    ],
    [
      "Jennifer Chang",
      "Regional Director",
      "Singapore",
      "9239",
      "2010/11/14",
      "$357,650"
    ],
    [
      "Brenden Wagner",
      "Software Engineer",
      "San Francisco",
      "1314",
      "2011/06/07",
      "$206,850"
    ],
    [
      "Fiona Green",
      "Chief Operating Officer (COO)",
      "San Francisco",
      "2947",
      "2010/03/11",
      "$850,000"
    ],
    [
      "Shou Itou",
      "Regional Marketing",
      "Tokyo",
      "8899",
      "2011/08/14",
      "$163,000"
    ],
    [
      "Michelle House",
      "Integration Specialist",
      "Sydney",
      "2769",
      "2011/06/02",
      "$95,400"
    ],
    [
      "Suki Burks",
      "Developer",
      "London",
      "6832",
      "2009/10/22",
      "$114,500"
    ],
    [
      "Prescott Bartlett",
      "Technical Author",
      "London",
      "3606",
      "2011/05/07",
      "$145,000"
    ],
    [
      "Gavin Cortez",
      "Team Leader",
      "San Francisco",
      "2860",
      "2008/10/26",
      "$235,500"
    ],
    [
      "Martena Mccray",
      "Post-Sales support",
      "Edinburgh",
      "8240",
      "2011/03/09",
      "$324,050"
    ],
    [
      "Unity Butler",
      "Marketing Designer",
      "San Francisco",
      "5384",
      "2009/12/09",
      "$85,675"
    ],
    [
      "Howard Hatfield",
      "Office Manager",
      "San Francisco",
      "7031",
      "2008/12/16",
      "$164,500"
    ],
    [
      "Hope Fuentes",
      "Secretary",
      "San Francisco",
      "6318",
      "2010/02/12",
      "$109,850"
    ],
    [
      "Vivian Harrell",
      "Financial Controller",
      "San Francisco",
      "9422",
      "2009/02/14",
      "$452,500"
    ],
    [
      "Timothy Mooney",
      "Office Manager",
      "London",
      "7580",
      "2008/12/11",
      "$136,200"
    ],
    [
      "Jackson Bradshaw",
      "Director",
      "New York",
      "1042",
      "2008/09/26",
      "$645,750"
    ],
    [
      "Olivia Liang",
      "Support Engineer",
      "Singapore",
      "2120",
      "2011/02/03",
      "$234,500"
    ],
    [
      "Bruno Nash",
      "Software Engineer",
      "London",
      "6222",
      "2011/05/03",
      "$163,500"
    ],
    [
      "Sakura Yamamoto",
      "Support Engineer",
      "Tokyo",
      "9383",
      "2009/08/19",
      "$139,575"
    ],
    [
      "Thor Walton",
      "Developer",
      "New York",
      "8327",
      "2013/08/11",
      "$98,540"
    ],
    [
      "Finn Camacho",
      "Support Engineer",
      "San Francisco",
      "2927",
      "2009/07/07",
      "$87,500"
    ],
    [
      "Serge Baldwin",
      "Data Coordinator",
      "Singapore",
      "8352",
      "2012/04/09",
      "$138,575"
    ],
    [
      "Zenaida Frank",
      "Software Engineer",
      "New York",
      "7439",
      "2010/01/04",
      "$125,250"
    ],
    [
      "Zorita Serrano",
      "Software Engineer",
      "San Francisco",
      "4389",
      "2012/06/01",
      "$115,000"
    ],
    [
      "Jennifer Acosta",
      "Junior Javascript Developer",
      "Edinburgh",
      "3431",
      "2013/02/01",
      "$75,650"
    ],
    [
      "Cara Stevens",
      "Sales Assistant",
      "New York",
      "3990",
      "2011/12/06",
      "$145,600"
    ],
    [
      "Hermione Butler",
      "Regional Director",
      "London",
      "1016",
      "2011/03/21",
      "$356,250"
    ],
    [
      "Lael Greer",
      "Systems Administrator",
      "London",
      "6733",
      "2009/02/27",
      "$103,500"
    ],
    [
      "Jonas Alexander",
      "Developer",
      "San Francisco",
      "8196",
      "2010/07/14",
      "$86,500"
    ],
    [
      "Shad Decker",
      "Regional Director",
      "Edinburgh",
      "6373",
      "2008/11/13",
      "$183,000"
    ],
    [
      "Michael Bruce",
      "Javascript Developer",
      "Singapore",
      "5384",
      "2011/06/27",
      "$183,000"
    ],
    [
      "Donna Snider",
      "Customer Support",
      "New York",
      "4226",
      "2011/01/25",
      "$112,000"
    ]
  ],
      dom: 'lBfrtip',
        
        
        buttons: [    {
               "extend": 'excelHtml5',
               "stripHtml": true, 
               "tag": 'img',
               "className": "btn-excel",
               "title": 'nokia(alu)_zayiflama',
               "titleAttr": 'Excel', 
               "attr": {
              src: '../images/menu_img/excel.ico'
          },                              
               
            },],
        
        
    } );
   
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
div.dataTables_scrollHead {
  position: sticky !important;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(82, 63, 105, 0.08);
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting {
    background: url("") no-repeat scroll right center rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
table.datatable th {
    font-size: 10px; 
    position: sticky;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

table.datatable td {
    font-size: 9px; 
}
div.dt-buttons {
    position:relative;
    bottom: 65px;
    left: 263px;
     width: 30%;
    }
img.btn-excel {
     width: 8%;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="datatable display nowrap cell-border compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead style="border-bottom: 0 solid; position:sticky; overflow-x: hidden;">
           <td align="center" class="arama"><input class="column_filter form-control" type="text""></td>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of creating 3 separate code snippets in your question (each of which does not run correctly, when you click their blue "run..." buttons), you can create one code snippet and place all of your HTML, CSS, and JS in that. Make sure that the snippet **demonstrates the problem you are asking about**, when you run the code snippet. (Otherwise, don't use code snippets. Just show us the relevant code, and library versions, as formatted text, with some test data.)

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, I edited my post, unfortunately I can't provide the running version of the code because it's against company policy.

Comment: We don't need the running version of your code; we only need a [mre]. And I think for a MRE (one that is specific to your problem) you don't need `serverSide: true` and you don't need any Ajax. Just some hard-coded data. What we have now is not a MRE because no-one can copy/paste and run the code you are showing us - at least not without a lot of extra work unrelated to your problem.

Comment: alright, I guess this time I got it right and added the working snippet. thank you again

Comment: Thank you for the updates - much appreciated. I took your code and ran it in a standalone web page in Chrome Version 113.0.5672.64 and in Edge Version 112.0.1722.68. Both worked correctly, with every test/action I could think of. Unfortunately, this means your code is still not a MRE - the 'R' is missing.